# How would I calculate Class A and B IP address ranges in Java when using a subnet mask?

Tags: java, android-studio, network-programming

```
public void cCalc() {

    oct1 = oct1 & sm1;
    oct2 = oct2 & sm2;
    oct3 = oct3 & sm3;
    oct4 = oct4 & sm4;

    String binString;
    binString = Integer.toBinaryString(sm1) + Integer.toBinaryString(sm2) +
            Integer.toBinaryString(sm3) + Integer.toBinaryString(sm4);

    int count = 0;
    for (int loop = 0; loop < binString.length(); loop++) {
        if (binString.charAt(loop) == '1') {
            count++;
        }
    }

    int hostBits = 32 - count;
    int hostsAvailable = (int) Math.pow(2, hostBits) - 2; //2^n - 2

    int extraBits = count - 24;
    int networksAvailable = (int) Math.pow(2, extraBits);

    System.out.println("Hosts per Network = " + hostsAvailable);
    System.out.println("Number of Networks = " + networksAvailable);

    String finalCalc = "";

    for (int loop = 1; loop <= networksAvailable; loop++) {
        //ID
        finalCalc = finalCalc + " Network ID: " + oct1 + "." + oct2 + "." + oct3 + "." + oct4;


        //Start
        oct4 = oct4 + 1;
        finalCalc = finalCalc + "\n Subnet Range(s): " + oct1 + "." + oct2 + "." + oct3 + "." + oct4 + " to ";

        //End
        oct4 = oct4 + hostsAvailable - 1;
        finalCalc = finalCalc + " " + oct1 + "." + oct2 + "." + oct3 + "." + oct4;

        //BroadcastAddress
        oct4 = oct4 + 1;
        finalCalc = finalCalc + "\n Broadcast address: " + oct1 + "." + oct2 + "." + oct3 + "." + oct4;

        //For next ID
        oct4 = oct4 + 1;

        finalCalc = finalCalc + "\n";

        setResult(finalCalc);

    }
}
```

This is my class C IP address range calculating method in my Subnet range calculator app - While I understand the calculation required for Class C, the calculation for Class A and B seems impossible to me.

How would I even begin to calculate Class A and B? I've been googling relentlessly and using trial and error for the past week or so now, but I can't seem to understand it.

Any advice or information would be fantastic.

(Also please excuse my probably poor code, I'm a complete beginner in Java)

Comment: You don't need to convert to a String to count bits. The `Integer` class has a method for that, [`bitCount`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount(int)).

Comment: Network classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (two years _before_ the commercial Internet in 1995!) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). We have not had classful networking in this century! Keep telling your self, "There is no such thing as classful networking," over and over until you know it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the project I've been set by my University - Trust me, I believe you when you say they're dead. I somehow still need to know how to calculate them though...

Comment: In any case, the network mask had nothing to do with a network class when they did exist. Network classes were defined by the first few bits of the address. [This answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/51918/8499) describes the difference between network classes.

Comment: Thanks for that link - While I understand what a Class A and B address is, it's the actual calculation (Or at least coding that calculation using Java) that's throwing me off. Not to sure where to start with it. I've had an idea of capping oct3 and oct4 to 255, but I'm not sure that would actually work (or could even be considered a viable calculator)